# content-type application/download works in Win7/IE8 but not in Win7/IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, contenttype

Background: Our production environment runs (legacy) vbscript both client- and server-side. So we are still on IE8. We're looking into upgrading client PCs to IE11. One problem we found is our file-downloads-for-display-in-browser no longer works. When clicking on, say, "test.xlsx" on the screen, which then calls a vbscript that does the following:

```
...
(read blob from database which can be pdf, xls, etc.)
....
If Not objRec.BOF And Not objRec.EOF Then

   lngSize = objRec("document").ActualSize
   objBlob = objRec("document").GetChunk(lngSize)

   Response.ContentType = "application/download"
   Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition","attachment; filename=""" + objRec("file_name") + """"
   Response.BinaryWrite objBlob
...
```

we get the prompt:

"Do you want to open or save download_asp?id=1616 from dev.ourintranet.com?"

with options to "Open", "Save", and "Cancel".

Clicking Open does nothing. 
Clicking Save opens directory common dialog but hitting Save does nothing.
Clicknig Cancel does nothing.

Why does it not work on IE11 anymore? Thanks a lot!

Comment: On the Open Save Cancel prompt, if I click Save, the dialog box actually defaults to the URL string "save download_asp?id=1616" which isn't a valid filename. If I change it to say, "c:\test.txt", then it saves. I can open c:\test.txt in Notepad.

Comment: Did you find a solution so far? I am facing the same issue with ASP.NET and IE11/Win7 too.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side VBScript no longer works in [IE11 edge mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057):

> As of Internet Explorer 11, VBScript is considered deprecated and should no longer be used as a scripting language for IE11. Webpages displayed in IE11 mode won't execute VBScript code.
>
> Because VBScript is no longer supported for IE11 mode, the following API features are no longer available to webpages:

```
The execScript function.
The VBArray object.
The "text/vbs" and "text/vbscript" MIME types (as supported type values for script elements).
```

> Update any pages that currently rely on VBSscript to use JavaScript. If this isn't feasible, try replacing the webpage with an app written in Visual Basic.
>
> For compatibility reasons, VBScript does execute for legacy document modes (IE10 standards mode and earlier), however, this should be considered a temporary solution.